# Finding the range of a semicircle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How would one go about ALGEBRAICALLY finding the range of a semicircle?

eg. $y = \sqrt{4-x^2}$

Since there is no plus-minus sign, we know that $y$ must at least have a range of $[0, \infty)$. Yet this must not be the complete case because we know a semicircle has restrictions on how small AND how big the $y$ value can be.

Comment: I would suggest you find the domain first. Then see what the y-values can be based on that.

Comment: I did. it is [-1,1]. And I am aware the one of the future steps is to make x = 0 to find one limit on the range. But why should we go this step x = 0?

Comment: @Lawrence: how did you get [-1,1] for the domain?

Comment: Since, in Real Analysis, you can **not** take the square root of a negative number, and since the square of a number is never negative, you have that $$0 \leq x^2 \leq 4.$$  This makes it **game over**.

Comment: @Lawrence. I meant -2 to 2

Comment: Yes, the domain is $[-2, 2]$.  Try transforming the equation $y = \sqrt{4 - x^2}$ into the equation of a circle.  That should help you determine its center and radius, from which you can determine the range.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please edit your question to show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x, y$ are real numbers, $y = \sqrt{4 - x^2}$ is only defined if $4 - x^2 \geq 0$.
\begin{align*}
4 - x^2 & \geq 0\\
4 & \geq x^2\\
2 & \geq |x| && \text{(take the square root of each side of the equation)}
\end{align*}
Since $|x| \leq 2$, $-2 \leq x \leq 2$.  Thus, as you noted in the comments, the domain of the function is $[-2, 2]$.

Since $\sqrt{t}$ denotes the nonnegative square root of $t$, $y = \sqrt{4 - x^2} \geq 0$.

\begin{align*}
y & = \sqrt{4 - x^2}\\
y^2 & = 4 - x^2 && \text{(square each side of the equation)}
\end{align*}
subject to the restriction that $y \geq 0$.  Since $x^2 \geq 0$, with equality holding if and only if $x = 0$, $y^2 \leq 4$ and $y \geq 0$.

\begin{align*}
y^2 & \leq 4\\
|y| & \leq 2 && \text{(take the square root of each side of the inequality)}
\end{align*}
Since $|y| \leq 2$, $-2 \leq y \leq 2$.  Since $-2 \leq y \leq 2$ and $y \geq 0$, $0 \leq y \leq 2$.  Thus, the range of the function is $[0, 2]$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are concerned with real $y$ we have:
$$y=\sqrt{4-x^2}\in\mathbb{R} \implies 4-x^2\geq0\implies x^2\leq4$$
also$$ x\in\mathbb{R} \implies x^2\geq0 \implies 0\leq x^2\leq 4$$
Hence:
$$0\leq4-x^2\leq4$$
So, then the maximum value of $y$ is:
$$ \sqrt{4} = 2$$
This *is* an algebraic approach but just to be sure you are satisfied I'll also use differentiation to find the maxiumum:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{4-x^2}} = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$$
Then:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \implies x=0$$
Substituting $x=0$ into $y$:
$$y\rvert_{x=0}=\sqrt{4}=2$$
We can see that this is the maximum easily if we consider the circle geometrically but if you wanted to use *purely algebra* you could find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and evaluate it at $x=0$ to get $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\rvert_{x=0}<0 $ which implies this stationary point is the maximum of y.